# MultipartUtility Java Class not working properly

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use this class i found online to upload multipart form data from an android activity to a web server. The class works anytime i use it to send three or more form data to the web server but it only sends one form data (the first one) when i try to use it to submit a form with just two fields in it. I don't know much about networking protocols except for the basics (200 etc) which is why i need the third party class in the first place or I would have written mine plus it is easy to use. I would very much appreciate if someone can rewrite and test it for me. A very simple to use alternative will be appreciated, too. thanks. the class:

```
public class MultipartUtility {
private  final Logger log = getLogger(MultipartUtility.class
        .getName());

private static final String CRLF = "\n";
private static final String CHARSET = "UTF-8";

private static final int CONNECT_TIMEOUT = 15000;
private static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;

private final HttpURLConnection connection;
private final OutputStream outputStream;
private final PrintWriter writer;
private final String boundary;

// for log formatting only
private final URL url;
private final long start;

public MultipartUtility(final URL url) throws IOException {
    start = currentTimeMillis();
    this.url = url;

    boundary = "---------------------------" + currentTimeMillis();

    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT);
    connection.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", CHARSET);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
            "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
    connection.setUseCaches(false);
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);

    outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
    writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, CHARSET),
            true);
}

public void addFormField(final String name, final String value) {
    writer.append("--").append(boundary).append(CRLF)
            .append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"").append(name)
            .append("\"").append(CRLF)
            .append("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=").append(CHARSET)
            .append(CRLF).append(CRLF).append(value).append(CRLF);
}

public void addFilePart(final String fieldName, final File uploadFile)
        throws IOException {
    final String fileName = uploadFile.getName();
    writer.append("--").append(boundary).append(CRLF)
            .append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"")
            .append(fieldName).append("\"; filename=\"").append(fileName)
            .append("\"").append(CRLF).append("Content-Type: ")
            .append(guessContentTypeFromName(fileName)).append(CRLF)
            .append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary").append(CRLF)
            .append(CRLF);

    writer.flush();
    outputStream.flush();
    try {
        final FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);
        final byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    writer.append(CRLF);
}

public void addHeaderField(String name, String value) {
    writer.append(name).append(": ").append(value).append(CRLF);
}

public byte[] finish() throws IOException {
    writer.append(CRLF).append("--").append(boundary).append("--")
            .append(CRLF);
    writer.close();

    final int status = connection.getResponseCode();
    if (status != HTTP_OK) {
        throw new IOException(format("{0} failed with HTTP status: {1}",
                url, status));
    }

    try {
        final InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        final ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        final byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            bytes.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        is.close(); //close
        log.log(INFO,
                format("{0} took {4} ms", url,
                        (currentTimeMillis() - start)));
        return bytes.toByteArray();
    } finally {
        connection.disconnect();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Use `Retrofit` for multiple Multipart Data

Comment: give me a link to it, thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41205070/5773037 try it